# Match a Regular Expression by simple 2 cases:

Tags: regex, expression, pascal, fpc

I'm trying to use a Regex Pattern in FPC (Free Pascal) - more here: http://wiki.freepascal.org/IDE_regular_expressions

HOWEVER! I can't determine how to match the first occurrence (if any) of a 3or4 lowercase (a-z) character strand.

I'd then proceed to trying the same expression but this time allowing upper case & numbers in to make a 3or4 char strand.

Help Appreciated! :]

---

For example (Things I've tried + examples):

```
s := 'My Name';
// I want the 'ame' portion 1st since there exists a consecutive string of 3 lowercase chars.

// Attempts:    
SplitRegExpr('[[:alnum:]]{3,4}');
SplitRegExpr('[a-z]{3,4}');
SplitRegExpr('[[:alnum:]]{3,4}?');
```

In response to Ken White, I think this is the right link, no?
http://www.gnu-pascal.de/gpc/RegEx.html
I understand the definitions, but I fail to see how to use them properly to create (for example what I'm trying to do) match patterns and what returns from them.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far that isn't working for you? What are some sample strings you're searching and results you're trying to get? This really isn't a site for "Here's a link to the documentation. Here's a general idea of what I'm trying to do. Got an answer?" type questions. (Actually, you never even ask a question at all.) Please [edit] your question to provide specifics, and the efforts you've made trying to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: The link you posted refers to regular expressions in the FreePascal IDE (the link is to `IDE_regular_expressions`), not in FreePascal code. Do you have a link to the actual FP runtime library regex unit?

Comment: gpc/gnu pascal is totally unrelated to Free Pascal/fpc. Newer ones feature the wellknown tregexpr by Andrey V. Sorokin in unit regexpr. I can't help since I don't really regexp.

Comment: There is no built-in support for reexpr in FPC (see: http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Regexpr ). Have you tried looking at the documentation for the library that you are using? Is your problem relatedd to writing regex or to the function calls?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a program extracting all the 3 or 4 lowercase character sequences.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$IFDEF FPC}{$MODE DELPHI}{$ENDIF}

uses
  regexpr;

var
  expr: TRegExpr;

begin
  expr := TRegExpr.Create;

  expr.Expression := '[a-z]{3,4}';

  if expr.Exec('My Name is Bunny.') then
    repeat
      WriteLn(expr.Match[0]);
    until not expr.ExecNext;

  expr.Free;
  ReadLn;
end.
```